# Add a list of multisets in python

Tags: python, multiset

What is the pythonic way to merge a list of `multiset`s into a single multiset?

For example,

```
from multiset import Multiset

set1 = Multiset('aab')
set2 = Multiset('abc')
ls = [set1, set2]
```

Based on using `set`s my guess was:

```
Multiset.add(*ls)
```

This gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/multiset.py", line 931, in add
self._elements[element] += multiplicity
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Multiset'
```

Is there a better way than a `for` loop, as below?

```
def add_multisets(ls):
    result = Multiset()
    for i in ls:
        result += i
    return result

>>> add_multisets(ls)
Multiset({'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1})
```

Comment: What is `Multiset`?

Comment: …and what is "an error" exactly?

Comment: if you want output like this `{'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}` you can use `collections.Counter`

Comment: Someone closed this?? Which part is unclear?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica The mathematical meaning is a set where each element can have repeats, the number of which is called the *multiplicity* of the element: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset

Comment: @JamesHirschorn: I know what a multiset is. That doesn't automatically tell me what `Multiset` is.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica At this point, I think it should be clear that it is a python package that implements this concept. Perhaps you asked before my edit `from multiset import Multiset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Multiset.combine(*ls)
i.e

```
from multiset import Multiset
set1 = Multiset('aab')
set2 = Multiset('abc')
ls = [set1, set2]
x = Multiset.combine(*ls)
print(x)  # Multiset({'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 2})
```